# Could not connect to Database Worklight

Tags: java, sql, db2, ibm-mobilefirst

I created a Worklight database using my local (internal) ip address and my server.xml references my internal ip address not my external. Does that matter? Here is the error I found in my console log -- I just wanted to note, my port :446 is NOT OPEN in my firewall. Would that cause this error?

```
[2/10/15 20:23:09:975 EST] 00001815 com.ibm.worklight.admin.actions.BaseTransaction              I Result: WLNativeSales360: defaultServer///(MY INTERNAL IP): Commit
[2/10/15 20:23:09:975 EST] 00001815 com.ibm.worklight.admin.actions.BaseTransaction              I WLNativeSales360: defaultServer///(MY INTERNAL IP): 2015-02-11T01:23:09.969Z: Operation to deploy adapter SQLAdapter was commited
[2/10/15 20:23:09:989 EST] 00001815 SystemErr                                                    R 53587426  WorklightManagementPU-db2  INFO   [pool-3-thread-3] openjpa.Runtime - Though you are using optimistic transactions, OpenJPA is now beginning a datastore transaction because you have requested a lock on some data.
[2/10/15 20:46:04:498 EST] 000017e0 com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet                              I SRVE0242I: [WLNativeSales360] [/WLNativeSales360] [GadgetAPIServlet]: Initialization successful.
[2/10/15 20:46:04:784 EST] 000017e0 SystemOut                                                    O com.ibm.net.SocketKeepAliveParameters
[2/10/15 20:49:14:785 EST] 000017e0 com.worklight.adapters.sql.SQLConnectionManager              E FWLSE0012E: ERROR: Could not connect to database. Cannot create PoolableConnectionFactory ([jcc][t4][2043][11550][3.63.123] Exception java.net.ConnectException: Error opening socket to server /(MY EXTERNAL IP) on port 446 with message: Connection timed out. ERRORCODE=-4499, SQLSTATE=08001). [project WLNativeSales360]
[2/10/15 20:54:43:076 EST] 000018b0 com.worklight.adapters.sql.SQLConnectionManager              E FWLSE0012E: ERROR: Could not connect to database. Cannot create PoolableConnectionFactory ([jcc][t4][2043][11550][3.63.123] Exception java.net.ConnectException: Error opening socket to server /(MY EXTERNAL IP) on port 446 with message: Connection timed out. ERRORCODE=-4499, SQLSTATE=08001). [project WLNativeSales360]
[2/10/15 20:59:21:796 EST] 000018b0 com.worklight.adapters.sql.SQLConnectionManager              E FWLSE0012E: ERROR: Could not connect to database. Cannot create PoolableConnectionFactory ([jcc][t4][2043][11550][3.63.123] Exception java.net.ConnectException: Error opening socket to server /(MY EXTERNAL IP) on port 446 with message: Connection timed out. ERRORCODE=-4499, SQLSTATE=08001). [project WLNativeSales360]
[2/11/15 5:29:54:423 EST] 00000055 com.ibm.puremeap.listeners.AppCenterServletContextListener   I cleaning the database leaks at Wed Feb 11 05:29:54 EST 2015
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the actual error:

> Exception java.net.ConnectException: Error opening socket to server
>   /(MY EXTERNAL IP) on port 446 with message: Connection timed out.
>   ERRORCODE=-4499, SQLSTATE=08001)

[Google results](https://www.google.co.il/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=db2%20errorcode%3D-4499%2C%20sqlstate%3D08001)

1. Make sure the server is actually up & running
2. I suppose you could use localhost for the database since you're working locally?
3. Not a network expert, but if it tries to connect using the external IP and the port is blocked in your firewall, you may want to open it?

Comment: I opened up the port. I am just waiting for the next log file to come in. Do those other errors mean anything? I was clicking around on the server and the logs are still not updated, so I take it to mean there are no errors?

Comment: The error I mentioned is the only error. As for what's happening in your server, you're the one to tell as you have the power...

Comment: Hi Idan -- I checked the log files and I am getting the same error. I opened port 446 in the firewall with the result of the same error.

Comment: I have set my db2comm to TCPIP previously

Comment: port 446 is on the mainframe where my other database is

Comment: Hi Idan, I verified my connectivity to my DB2 on z/OS database with my internal and external IP's using port 446. Is there anything I need to do on Worklight's end to go to the db2 on z/OS database?

Comment: It could be the database definition in the worklight.properties?

Comment: The worklight database I made using the ant tasks went to my local db2 database that was on my server not my z/OS server. The application connects to worklight and then connects  to db2 on z/OS. Any ideas?

Comment: what are database definition in the adapter.xml? add them to the question

Comment: I don't have an adapter.xml file. When I installed Worklight it was to my local DB2 database. ANT -F also went to my local DB2 database. Does that even matter? The APP is just using Worklight to connect to that database

Comment: 000017e0 com.worklight.adapters.sql.SQLConnectionManager  - your application has an SQL adapter that attempts to connect to a database...